# Why hang glider dont over pitch when inrease AoA?

Tags: stability, hang-glider

Glider change AoA with changing c.g.
To do that,you must push control bar forward,your c.g. move back,so we have torque in clockwise direction which wants rotate glider..
Situation can be even worse,because increased AoA shift center of pressure(lift) more forward.

Why glider dont over pitch(and stall),what stop this dangerous torque when you must fly with higer AoA?What gives glider restoring torque if he dont has tail?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that the wing itself is designed to have sufficient excess pitch stability such that the glider-pilot system is still stable in pitch when the pilot's weight is shifted *somewhat* aft.  If the pilot's weight is shifted *sufficiently* far aft, however, a stall may occur. The glider might not recover into stable flight if the control bar is kept pushed *that* far forward, i.e. if the pilot's weight is kept shifted *that* far aft.

It is normal to trim a hang glider to fly in wings-level flight at an airspeed near the minimum sink rate, not too far above stall speed, when the pilot is exerting no pressure on the control bar.  It would be normal for the glider to stall if the pilot extends his arms as far forward as he can reach, in wings-level flight.  A hang glider pilot would not necessarily expect to see benign flight characteristics if he keeps the bar pushed forward as far as his arms can reach, in wings-level flight.

Comment: What gives glider restoring moment if he dont has tail?If wing is rigid,will be stable again?

Comment: @EBV821 -- I've created a chat room to discuss hang glider dynamics further -- https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118737/a-room-to-talk-about-hang-glider-flight-dynamics